# Accessing Cloud sql server from windows mobile application

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, cloud

I have developed a windows mobile application with `SQL Compact Database`.
Now I want to use a remote `Cloud server`.

I tried and couldn't Connect to the server.
**the Application Error says**,

> A native exception has occurred in xxxxx.exe. Select quit and then
>   restart this program.....
>
> In error Detail section,
>
> ExceptionCode: 0xc0000005 ExceptionAddress: 0x03fa5938 Reading:
>   0x00000000

I have tried with another remote server (not a cloud server) and it worked fine.
Problem is when connecting to the Cloud server.
Cloud server is up & running.

*Also I am testing in Device Emulator and Windows mobile 6.*

Comment: What "cloud server"?  What code is causing the exception?

Comment: +1 Some of these websites today (here, for one) rely on being logged in to work. Is your device logged into your cloud?

Comment: can you post your connection strings? Do both server (the single one and the cloud one) support the same authentication?

Comment: Hi all,I am trying to connect to Windows Azure.Also I'm testing using the Device Emulator(DE).this error gives from DE when trying to connect to server.I'm using the IP address(xxx.xx.xxx.xxx,1433\SQLEXPRESS2008R2) in Con Stirng.I tried with the server name also.BUT not Working.

Comment: hi all,I have solved the problem. instead of using the IP ,I tested using the server name.earlier I have given the server name with another port number.